# Content Controls - hiding text

Tags: visual-studio

I love this Form Developer in Word 2010 and have been making fillable forms but how do I hide the "choose an item" text if I want the form to be printed and filled out manually so it looks clean and professional?

Comment: This is off-topic for SharePoint.StackExchange. You could try asking this on StackOverflow.com.

Answer (score 0):

This is not related to SharePoint at all... Not even to Visual Studio.

You can change the placeholder text if you click the Design Mode button in the Developer pane. It can't be empty, but you can put just an empty space. Note that it will make the control harder to spot on a form unless you use style, borders, etc. to make it stand out.